# Proving a function is one-to-one and surjective

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions

I'm trying to use the function $f: (0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

$$f(x)=\frac{(x-\frac{1}{2})^3}{x(x-1)}$$ to show that the real numbers are as many as the numbers in the interval $(0,1)$.

However, it seems to be a little harder than I thought to prove that $f$ is bijective. Is it obvious and I'm just stumped right now or is actually difficult? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @PeterForeman I guess there are more functions, like $f(x)=1/(1+exp(x))$ but how do I show it using this one?

Comment: Or even $f(x)=(x-\frac12)/(x(x-1))$. Why cube the numerator?

Answer (score 2):

Since$$f'(x)=\frac{(1-2 x)^2 \left(2 x^2-2 x-1\right)}{8 (x-1)^2 x^2},$$which is always smaller than $0$ in $(0,1)$ (except at $\frac12$, which is a zero of $f'$), $f$ is strictly decreasing. And since$$\lim_{x\to1^-}f(x)=-\infty\text{ and }\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=\infty,$$it follows from the continuity of $f$ and from the intermediate value theorem that $f$ is surjective.

Answer (score 0):

The derivative of the function is - 
$$\frac{(2x-1)^2(2x^2-2x-1)}{8x^2(x-1)^2}$$
In the interval $(0,1)$ the derivative is negative, which means that the function is strictly monotone (and so injective).

When $x\rightarrow 0^+$, the function tends to infinity. When $x\rightarrow 1^-$,the function tends to minus infinity. The function is continuous in the open interval, and so by the intermediate value theorem, the function attains any value in the range $(-\infty, \infty)$ in the given interval, and it thus surjective.

Answer (score 0):

$$
f'(x) = \frac{3(x-\frac 12)^2x(x-1) - 2(x-\frac 12)^4}{x^2(x-1)^2} = \left(\frac{x-\frac 12}{x(x-1)}\right)^2\cdot\left((x-\tfrac 12)^2-\tfrac 34\right) \le 0.
$$